# instance expected, got OrderedDict Django Rest Framework writable nested serializers

Tags: nested, django-rest-framework, serialization, writable

I am creating a survey kind of app, so i have three models Form, Questiosn, Choices[for multiple choice questions]

I followed this tutorial http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

It works fine for 1 level nested relations, but for 2 levels it gives

**TypeError: 'Choice' instance expected, got OrderedDict([(u'title', u'option1')])**

```
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['title']

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ['title', 'type', 'required','order','choices']

    def create(self, validated_data):
    choices_data = validated_data.pop("choices")
    question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for choice_data in choices_data:
        Choice.objects.create(question=question, **choice_data)
    return question

class FormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
    model = Form
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'created', 'active', 'hash','questions']
    read_only_fields = ['active','hash']

    def create(self, validated_data):
    questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
    form = Form.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for question_data in questions_data:
        Question.objects.create(form=form, **question_data)
    return form
```

**EDIT**

Solved using the manual way, In FormSerializer override the create method,

```
@transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
                form = Form.objects.create(**validated_data)
                for question_data in questions_data:
                    question = Question.objects.create(form=form,
                                                       title=question_data['title'],
                                                       type=question_data['type'],
                                                       required=question_data['required'])
                    if question.type == Question.RADIO or question.type == Question.CHECKBOX:
                        choices_data = question_data.pop('choices')
                        for choice_data in choices_data:
                            choice = Choice.objects.create(question=question, title=choice_data['title'])
                return form
        except Exception, e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Cannot Save Form %s" % e)
```

Comment: Since I was not going any where with this, I did it the manual way

Answer (score 6):

I also struggled with this and I believe the proper way to handle this is:

```
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['title']

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title', 'type', 'required','order','choices']


class FormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Form
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'created', 'active', 
                 'hash','questions']
        read_only_fields = ['active','hash']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
        form = Form.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for question_data in questions_data:
            choices_data = question_data.pop('choices')
            Question.objects.create(form=form, **question_data)
            for choice_data in choices_data:
                choice = Choice.objects.create(question=question, **choice_data)
        return form
```

An easy way to screw this up is to not pop choices before creating the Question object. When you do that, you'll get an `instance expected, got OrderedDict(` 500 error.

Note also that you do not need to define create() on the QuestionSerializer. All child processing is done at the top level.